# Incompatible Types error, Java

Tags: java, methods, error-handling, java.util.scanner, bluej

I'm having some trouble figuring out why I keep getting "incompatible types" error, so here is my sample code (Note: This is for an introductory Java coding course, and the teacher has a specific format we need to follow.) The primary objective is to use seperate methods to get the nouns, adjectives, and verbs for the Madlib, and return those to the main method for the full story.

```
public class MadLib{

//First, I will want to set my named constants

public static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String [] args){

    System.out.println("Hello there! Welcome to my MadLib!");
    System.out.println("Before we start, we need some words!");
    String n1   = getNoun();
    String n2   = getNoun();
    String a1   = getAdj();
    String a2   = getAdj();
    String v1   = getVerb();
    String ving = getVing();

}

private static void getNoun(){

    System.out.println("Please enter a noun!");
    noun = keyboard.nextLine();
    return noun;
```

Thanks for checking it out! I hope someone can help me. I think the problem is that I'm not sure how to return a string from the Scanner utility. Please, any help will do. Thank you!

Comment: Your method's return type is `void`, change it to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `String` from a `void` return typed method.If you want to return string from your method then method return type should `String`.
Change the return type of `getNoun()` method to `String` and return `keyboard.nextLine();` directly.

```
private static String getNoun(){    
    System.out.println("Please enter a noun!");
    return keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a String from your method. Change `private static void getNoun()` with `private static String getNoun()`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still making such dumb mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:-

```
private static void getNoun(){
```

to

```
private static String getNoun(){
               ^Here
```